# Silverlight: How to specify the body font?

Tags: .net, silverlight, xaml

If I can't use CSS, how can I specify body font for all the site in Silverlight 4?

```
body {
    color: #31404C;
    font-family: Arial;
    font-size: 10px;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the font properties for the root control of your page. If you want this to be standard across several pages (such as in a navigation-based application), you can specify the relevant styles in static resources and then bind the control's properties or overall style to those resources.

[This StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4341737/app-wide-font-resources-in-silverlight) provides some help on application-wide font resources. That question also includes a link to [this useful resource on Control Styles](http://www.silverlight.net/learn/quickstarts/control-styles/).

Comment: +1 for the root element. After tests I remarked that all child elements, navigation pages, etc, takes the same font as the container... this is pretty cool...